# How do I build a parser out of tokenizers?

Tags: java, parsing, jparsec

I am using [jparsec](/questions/tagged/jparsec) to parse strings like:

```
[1,2, 3]
[ 3, 4]
[3   ,4,56, 7 ]
[]
```

I have implemented a few classes (inheriting from my `Token` interface) to represent the tokens:

```
final class OpenListToken
final class CommaToken
final class CloseListToken
final class NumberToken // Has a public final property "value" that contains the int
```

I have also implemented tokenizers for each:

```
static final Parser<OpenListToken> openListTokenParser
static final Parser<CommaToken> commaTokenParser
static final Parser<CloseListToken> closeListTokenParser
static final Parser<NumberToken> numberTokenParser
```

These all work at a character level. For example:

```
final NumberToken t = numberTokenParser.parse("123");
// t.value == 123

final OpenListToken u = openListToken.parse("[");
// Succeeds
```

Now I would like to combine them to make a parser of `ListExpression`, which is a class than represents a list of numbers. I have tried something like:

```
openListTokenParser
    .next(numberTokenParser.sepBy(commaTokenParser))
    .followedBy(closeListTokenParser)
```

This works for strings like `[1,2,3]` but obviously not for strings like `[  1, 2 ]`.

Is there an operator that takes some parsers and puts `whitespace*` between them?

Or is it possible to make my `ListExpression` parser work on a stream of my `Token` interface instances instead of characters?

Comment: you want to ignore white spaces ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi correct

Comment: try this : `static final Parser<Void> IGNORED = Parsers.or(
    Scanners.JAVA_LINE_COMMENT,
    Scanners.JAVA_BLOCK_COMMENT,
    Scanners.WHITESPACES).skipMany();`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi How do I combine that `IGNORED` parser with my existing ones?

Comment: `Parser<T> parser = grammar.from(YOURTOKENIZER, IGNORED);`

Comment: How is `grammar` defined?

Comment: it's a parser defined before `Parser<T> grammar = ...`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi the `...` part is the bit I am trying to understand!

Comment: lemme introduce it in an answer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly build a tokenizer using the functions from `Terminals` class. In your case, this would look like the following:

First define the set of our terminals, e.g. operators, keywords, words...

```
Terminals terminals = operators("[", "]", ",");
```

Our tokens are then either tokenized by our terminals or the `IntegerLiteral` tokenizer:

```
Parser<?> tokens = Parsers.or(terminals.tokenizer(), IntegerLiteral.TOKENIZER);
```

Our final results from a syntactic parsers for integers (built from tokens tagged as `INTEGER`), separated by our comma token, between our brackets token. We ignore any whitespace in between all tokens (this is the second argument to `from`:

```
Parser<?> parser = IntegerLiteral.PARSER.sepBy(terminals.token(",")).between(terminals.token("["), terminals.token("]"))
  .from(tokens, Scanners.WHITESPACES.many().cast());
```

Et voilà:

```
System.out.println(parser.parse( "[1,2,3]"));
System.out.println(parser.parse( "[ 1, 2 , 3 ]   "));
System.out.println(parser.parse( "   [1,2,3   ]"));
System.out.println(parser.parse( "[1, 2   ,    3]"));
```

Comment: This token/string duality in jparsec is definitely confusing at first...